# Creating an Azure SQL Server without Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.Fluent

Tags: azure, azure-sdk

I want to programmatically create an Azure SQL Server and I found an example piece of code online

```
static void CreateServer()
{
    // Create a SQL Database management client
    SqlManagementClient sqlClient = new SqlManagementClient(new TokenCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, token.AccessToken));

    // Create a server
    ServerCreateOrUpdateParameters serverParameters = new ServerCreateOrUpdateParameters()
    {
        Location = location,
        Properties = new ServerCreateOrUpdateProperties()
        {
            AdministratorLogin = administratorLogin,
            AdministratorLoginPassword = administratorPassword,
            Version = serverVersion
        }
    };
        var serverResult = sqlClient.Servers.CreateOrUpdate(resourceGroupName, serverName, serverParameters);
}
```

... but I have since found that the packages I need for this are deprecated. Instead of Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.Fluent I should be using Azure.ResourceManager.Sql

But I can't find any example as clear as the above to create a new Azure SQL server using the new packages. This is an area I'm very unfamiliar with so I can't see the wood for the trees and I get lost in the definitions. Can someone please provide a code snippet as minimalistic as the above to achieve the same thing using new packages?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created SQL server in azure using the below C# code without `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.Fluent`

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
   {
      string tenant_Id = "TenantId";
      string clnt_Id = "ClientId";
      string clnt_Secrt = "Secret";
      string subscrip_Id = "SubscriptionID";

       string resource_GrpName = "Resource Group";
       string server_Name = "myservertest4411";
       string admin_Login = "Rajesh";
       string admin_Pwd = "Password";

       string authenticationUrl = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_Id}/oauth2/token";
       string requestBody = $"grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={clnt_Id}&client_secret={clnt_Secrt}&resource=https://management.azure.com/";
       var content = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

       using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                var res = await httpClient.PostAsync(authenticationUrl, content);
                string res_Content = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                string access_Token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(res_Content).access_token;

                string create_ServerUrl = $"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscrip_Id}/resourceGroups/{resource_GrpName}/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/{server_Name}?api-version=2021-02-01-preview";
                string server_RequestBody = $"{{ \"location\": \"eastus\", \"properties\": {{ \"administratorLogin\": \"{admin_Login}\", \"administratorLoginPassword\": \"{admin_Pwd}\", \"version\": \"12.0\" }} }}";
                var server_Req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, create_ServerUrl);
                server_Req.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", access_Token);
                server_Req.Content = new StringContent(server_RequestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                var server_Resp = await httpClient.SendAsync(server_Req);
                if (server_Resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("SQL Server created successfully!");
                }
                else
                {
                    string errorResponseContent = await server_Resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine($"Failed to create SQL Server. Error: {errorResponseContent}");
                }
            }
     }
```

[image]

In azure you can see the SQL server created.

[image]

- You need a create an app in the App registrations of Azure.
  [image]
- I have given the owner permissions to the app, depending on your requirement you can choose the permissions.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution for creating a SQL server and database using the new Azure.ResourceManager.Sql nuget package.

Creating server:

```
ArmClient armClient = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());
ResourceGroupResource resourceGroup = armClient.GetResourceGroupResource(new Azure.Core.ResourceIdentifier("RESOURCE_GROUP_ID_HERE"));
SqlServerCollection sqlServers = resourceGroup.GetSqlServers();
ArmOperation<SqlServerResource> serverOperation = await sqlServers.CreateOrUpdateAsync(Azure.WaitUntil.Completed, "MySqlServerName", new SqlServerData(Azure.Core.AzureLocation.WestEurope)
{
    AdministratorLogin = "MyLogin",
    AdministratorLoginPassword = "MySecretPassword",
    MinimalTlsVersion = "1.2"
});
```

Creating Database:

```
    ArmClient armClient = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());
    SqlServerResource serverResource = armClient.GetSqlServerResource(new Azure.Core.ResourceIdentifier("SQL_SERVER_ID_HERE"));
    SqlDatabaseData sqlDatabaseData = new SqlDatabaseData(Azure.Core.AzureLocation.WestEurope)
    {
        Sku = new SqlSku("Basic"),
        MaxSizeBytes = 2147483648, //2GB
    };
    sqlDatabaseData.Tags.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("I-LOVE-MICROSOFTS-DOCUMENTATION", "Yes"));
    SqlDatabaseCollection databaseCollection = serverResource.GetSqlDatabases();
    ArmOperation<SqlDatabaseResource> operation = await databaseCollection.CreateOrUpdateAsync(Azure.WaitUntil.Completed, "MyPerfectDatabaseName", sqlDatabaseData);
```

This creates a database on the Basic SKU (5 DTU), click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/get-azsqlserverserviceobjective?view=azps-11.0.0) to see all the different SKU's.

Comment: Thanks Michel - the question was about how to create a server, not a database, but I'm sure that in most cases creating a database is the natural thing to do after creating a server so I'm sure your comment will help some readers.

Comment: Hi, sorry I misread the question, i read what i wanted to read :). I've corrected my answer and also include how to create a SQL server with the package.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a million, Michel